# How Apache mod_rewrite Module works?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to make my own MVC PHP framework using a tutorial that i found over the net .
but i got a problem understanding the rewrite_mod in the htaccess files. here is the first part :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    public/     [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

1) As written in the tutorial those rules will redirect all the request to the public folder , so the first question is why we have two rules ? what means the first and the second. one
2) the second part is another htaccess file in the public folder containing :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

the second part will rewrite the url to index.php?url=$1 this part is clear but this part is little bit difficult for me

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

i learn about it and it tell that the request should not be a file or directory but the index.php is a file (in public directory) .
anothe question please why when we remove the last .htaccess file (in public directory)  we
got this error :

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at admin@127.0.0.1 to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

and when we have only a htacces containting only this part ,it works great ?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>
```

Thanks so much .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine and `fix` the root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !^public/ public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This means forward to `/public/<uri>` if REQUEST_URI does not start with `/public`

**Some explanation now.**

`DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule    ^$    public/     [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
```

1. 1st rule is internally forwarding to `public/` with request URI is empty i.e. `http://site.com/`
2. 2nd rule is internally forwarding even URI to `public/<URI>`

`DOCUMENT_ROOT/public/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
```

Here inside public direcotry:

1. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` means if request is not for a valid file
2. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` means if request is not for a valid directory
3. `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1` means forward request to `index.php?url=<uri>`

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: Thanks for the comment , i need to understand first how all this works :)

Comment: added some explanation

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f means if request is not for a valid file. but index.php in public folder is a file !

Comment: Yes that's correct so if you send request as `http://site.com/public/index.php` then rule will not fire.

Comment: I removed the two line : RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d and it still works fine all it redirected to index.php !!!! is this normal ? even for file/folder that do not exist

Comment: With those 2 conditions if there is an existing file in `/public/` that will also be forwarded to `/public/index.php?url=<uri>`

Comment: I added mod_rewrite reference in the answer.

Comment: ahh ok clear now !! i have another question please , how about the error when we remove the .htaccess file in public folder, thanks so much

Comment: When you removed `public/.htaccess` then `RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]` caused infinite looping and 500 error since it is **conditionally forwarding** every request to `/public/` and every rule execution gets injected again until rewrite limit is reached.

Comment: Normally when we redirect to the public folder we execute the index.php file , so don't understand why there is an infinite loop? Thank you.

Comment: Because apache keeps processing your rewrite rules until there a condition that stops all the rules. I suggest you do some reading on the reference I provided.